# Image Binding in gridview asp.net with find control property

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, gridview, webforms

I'm trying to set image source URL from button click event but gives error "EventArgs does not contain definition for row image gridview"

Gridview Code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Height="222px" Width="859px"  style="text-align:center;">
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Artist" Datafield="Artist"/>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Album" Datafield="Album"/>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Playcount" Datafield="Playcount"/>

                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Album Art">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" width="174px" height="174px"/>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                        </Columns>
                        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Binding from json:

```
protected void btnMusic_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (txtMusic.Text != null && txtMusic.Text != "")
        {
            string artist = txtMusic.Text;
            var requestUrl = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.gettopalbums&artist=" + artist + "&api_key=[]&format=json";
            var client = new WebClient();
            client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome / 58.0.3029.110 Safari / 537.36");
            var response = client.DownloadString(requestUrl);
            response = response.Replace(@"#text", "text");
            dynamic stuff = JObject.Parse(response);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Artist", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Album", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Playcount", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("AlbumArt", typeof(string));
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                lblInfo.InnerText = artist;
                name = (stuff.topalbums.album[i].name.ToString());
                playcount = stuff.topalbums.album[i].playcount.ToString();
                image = stuff.topalbums.album[i].image[2].text.ToString();
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image img = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image)e.Row.Cells[2].FindControl("Image1");
                img.ImageUrl = image;

                dt.Rows.Add(artist, name, playcount, image);
            }
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        else
            lblInfo.InnerText = "Please Enter an Artist Name";
    }
```

Here is the code throwing error:

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image img = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image)e.Row.Cells[2].FindControl("Image1");
img.ImageUrl = image; // This is where Error Comes
```

Comment: I can't find anything about `btnMusic_Submit` control in your code, is that a Button control ID and where is it located? If it's true, I can sure that the Button's EventArgs is used instead of Gridview one.

Comment: yes it is button control ID ... it is where its supposed to be in  .aspx page

Comment: Seems I found the problem source, can you clarify that `txtMusic` also belongs outside the gridview? A screenshot of your input page with gridview may help visualize gridview contents.

Comment: Also, name, playcount and image are not declared, that i can see.

Comment: tetsuya yes it belongs outside gridview

Comment: @wazz it is declared... only pasted code which i though was necessary for solution

Answer (score 0):

Change your template to

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Album Art">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Width="174px" Height="174px" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("AlbumArt") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Code behind change:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    lblInfo.InnerText = artist;
    string name = (stuff.topalbums.album[i].name.ToString());
    string playcount = stuff.topalbums.album[i].playcount.ToString();
    string image = stuff.topalbums.album[i].image[2].text.ToString();
    //System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image img = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image)e.Row.Cells[2].FindControl("Image1");
    //img.ImageUrl = image;

    dt.Rows.Add(artist, name, playcount, image);
}
```

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: works for me. what's the problem? are you sure you're getting the right data in 'stuff'?

Comment: yes .. everything works ... i am able to display playcount , album name etc

Comment: but when i try to bind image it says   "EventArgs does not contain definition for row image gridview"

in e.row e.Row.Cells[2](System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image)e.Row.Cells[2].FindControl("Image1");

Comment: You have to comment out those lines. you don't need them.

Comment: obliviously i removed them

Comment: and still getting error? you shouldn't be. error is here `e.Row`. you are inside a button event, not a gridview event. button does not have `Row` in its eventargs. error should be gone if those lines are commented out.

Comment: this the error i get 

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'EventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Row' and no extension method 'Row' accepting a first argument of type 'EventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)

Comment: Plz update your code in the original post so we can see what you have.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not this line

```
img.ImageUrl = image;
```

But the line before

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image img = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image)e.Row.Cells[2].FindControl("Image1");
```

You are using `e.Row.Cells`, but you are using this in a Button Click, not a RowDataBound event so `e` does not have a `Row` property. Use

```
GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("Image1");
```