# Manually add image url to image column in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, gridview

I am working on a project where I have to search some values in the `DataTable` and view the results with added image column, the image URLs are stored in a different table.

So far I was able to add the image type column in to the GridView but I am struggling to give image URLs into those image column cells.

This is how I have added the image column:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Student ID");
dt.Columns.Add("Semester");
dt.Columns.Add("Year");
dt.Columns.Add("Assigment 01");
dt.Columns.Add("Assigment 02");
dt.Columns.Add("Exam");
con.Open();
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (rdr.Read())
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["Student ID"] = rdr["StudentID"];
    dr["Semester"] = rdr["SemesterID"];
    dr["Year"] = rdr["Year"];
    dr["Assigment 01"] = rdr["Assigment_01"];
    dr["Assigment 02"] = rdr["Assigment_02"];
    dr["Exam"] = rdr["Exam"];
}
ImageField img = new ImageField();
img.HeaderText = "Image";
GridView1.Columns.Add(img);
GridView1.Visible = true;
```

Is there are way to feed image URLs into this newly add column from using a query?

Like this:

```
string ImagePaths = "Select Image from StudentData where StudentID="'+rdr["StudentID"]+'");
```

Comment: Possibly duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46922437/image-binding-in-gridview-asp-net-with-find-control-property

Answer (score 1):

You want to show Image in a GridView ?

if yes, then add a template column in a gridview and bind image path to it.

Comment: yes, but is there a way to do it programmatically instead of automating it ? Thank you.

Comment: What's your need for doing it programmatically? Just curious.

Comment: I have implemented my search feature in a way that I created query string from the user inputs and created a data table from the SqlDataReader as you can see above then giving the table as the data source of the grid view using this command                     'GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();'
Since theres no sql data source binded into the grid view i am not able to do it automatically, in addition i need to get the image urls from a different table and embed into this grid view. @IrishChieftain

Comment: that's not a solution? required more details.

Comment: Search has nothing to do with how you present your data; it is purely a database-access process.